# Linux mud client with sound?

Tags: linux, gnome

I use [MUSHclient](http://www.gammon.com.au/mushclient/mushclient.htm) under windows to play muds. I'd like a Linux mud client that can play sounds when a trigger is activated in the same way MUSHclient can under windows. The only Linux client I've used before is TinyFugue and it doesn't offer this ability. Note running MUSHclient under Wine is not an option.

Edit:

The client has to either be console based or Gnome based. I use screen reading software and it doesn't work under KDE.

Answer (score 1):

[GnomeMud](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeMud)  (formerly AMCL) is a Multi-User Dungeon (MUD) client that aims to make mudding a bit easier. It can define aliases, triggers, variables, keyboard shortcuts, and has a connection wizard for easy management of different player characters and MUDs.

[KMuddy](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/GAMES-ENTERTAINMENT/MUD/KMuddy-19610.shtml) is a MUD client powered by KDE. It is a very powerful, fast, feature-rich and easy to use MUD client.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have to either use a console based or Gnome based client. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: i have changed my answer ;)

Comment: @joe, i added back in the KDE tool's description to the answer.  glad you found a Gnome tool for the OP but you should leave the KDE tool link.  future readers might have the same question without the no-KDE dependency.

Comment: So IIRC tinyfugue can run a program as the response to a trigger.  So all that's needed is the proper commandline for whatever sound you want to play.  Many years ago, on Sun platforms, that was 'aucat' - as in 'aucat ~/sounds/bell.au' - dunno what replaces that for most soundfiles under linux today... but it's just a matter of firing it up, whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

I never found a Linux MUD client that I liked. I currently use Portal, which works perfectly in Wine, and according to [this](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=10320), so does MUSHclient.